# how to take date value from string in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, date, python-3.x

I'm fetch value from the URL.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('url')    
response.read()
```

It's give me too long string type output, but I only put here what I have issue.

STRING TYPE OUTPUT:

```
'<p>Dear Customer,</p>
<p>This notice serves as proof of delivery for the shipment listed below.</p>
<dl class="outHozFixed clearfix"><label>Weight:</label></dt><dd>18.00 lbs</dd>
<dt><label>Shipped&#047;Billed On:</label></dt><dd>09/11/2015</dd>
<dt><label>Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>09/14/2015 11:07 A.M.</dd>
<dt><label for="">Signed By:</label></dt><dd>Odedra</dd></dt>
<dt><label>Left At:</label></dt>
<dd>Office</dd></dl><p>Thank you for giving us this opportunity to serve you.</p>'
```

QUESTION:

how I can take date (09/14/2015 11:07 A.M.) which is assign for *Delivered On*?

Comment: If the time format has constant length. you might use like re.search('Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>(.*)$',a).group(1)[:20], where a is the string

Comment: @Vineesh, Thank you so much for your comments, your code works fine but it's fail when Delivered On: is empty. Here is error. *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'*

Comment: Can you add an check for it . Like  "data = re.search('Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>(.*)$',a)"   then   "if data: data.group(1)[:20]". This should handle Nonetype

Comment: I added but it's give me output this => *'</dd><dt><label for='*

Comment: the code is written in the answer box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import re

text = '''<p>Dear Customer,</p>
          <p>This notice serves as proof of delivery for the shipment listed below.</p>
          <dl class="outHozFixed clearfix"><label>Weight:</label></dt>
          <dd>18.00 lbs</dd>
          <dt><label>Shipped&#047;Billed On:</label></dt>
          <dd>09/11/2015</dd>
          <dt><label>Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>09/14/2015 11:07 A.M.</dd>
          <dt><label for="">Signed By:</label></dt><dd>Odedra</dd></dt>
          <dt><label>Left At:</label></dt>
          <dd>Office</dd></dl><p>Thank you for giving us this opportunity to serve you.</p>'''

re.findall(r'<dt><label>Delivered On:<\/label><\/dt><dd>([0-9\.\/\s:APM]+)', text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['09/14/2015 11:07 A.M.']
```

Answer (score 6):

You could start by using something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or some other html parser. It might look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('url')    
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
datestr = soup.find("label", text="Delivered On:").find_parent("dt").find_next_sibling("dd").string
```

And if you need to, once you have a hold of the date string, you can use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert it to a datetime object.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%mm/%dd/%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Remember - you generally should not find yourself parsing HTML or XML with regexes...

Comment: "Never Say Never Again". If you want to parse 1B of letters, it's better to write you own tool to parse html instead of using `BeatifulSoup`, because Soup is a tool for html analyze. And it does a lot of work, that you (probably) don't need. Also, Soup are not memory efficient.

Comment: haha okay yes you're right... never say never. I just was thinking about this famous question (and top answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Now it's much better ;) Here is your +1 :) Btw, look into second answer from that topic :)

Comment: @Jimilian: no, regex is even less of an answer with larger masses of XML. There are fast tools to parse XML that are not BeautifulSoup. Doesn't mean regex is the only alternative.

Comment: In general, there are XML parsers that build up a useable DOM presentation (like BS) and then there are parsers that read a stream of XML into a tokenized stream, usually only used when the input XML doesn't fit into the memory.

Comment: @stett, Thank you so much for your answer. I use your answered code but it give me error *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'*

Comment: @Odedra: the label text was impresice. If you don't need the exact match; you could use `text=re.compile('Delivered On')` instead.

Comment: `strptime()` also fails. You could use `.strptime(datestr.replace('A.M.', 'am').replace('P.M.', 'pm'), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on that output only, I would use `re` and `re.search`. Create a regex for finding a date with time, like this:

```
import re

output = '''<p>Dear Customer,</p>
            <p>This notice serves as proof of delivery for the shipment listed below.</p>
            <dl class="outHozFixed clearfix"><label>Weight:</label></dt><dd>18.00 lbs</dd>
            <dt><label>Shipped&#047;Billed On:</label></dt><dd>09/11/2015</dd>
            <dt><label>Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>09/14/2015 11:07 A.M.</dd>
            <dt><label for="">Signed By:</label></dt><dd>Odedra</dd></dt>
            <dt><label>Left At:</label></dt>
            <dd>Office</dd></dl><p>Thank you for giving us this opportunity to serve you.</p>'''

pattern = '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [A|P]\.M\.'

result = re.search(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE).group(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works fine but it's fail when Delivered On: is empty. Here is error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like regexp and third-part libraries, you always can use old-school hardcoded one-line solution:

```
import datetime

text_date = [item.strip() for item in input_text.split('\n') if "Delivered On:" in item][0][41:-5]
datetime.datetime.strptime(text_date.replace(".",""), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
```

For one line case:

```
start_index = input_text.index("Delivered On:")+len("Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>")
stop_index = start_index + 21
text_date = input_text[start_index:stop_index]
```

Because any solution for your question will be a different type of hardcode :(

Comment: thank you for your answer. But this code will not fetch the date.

Comment: if you test @Alexandr Faizullin code, I get what i want. But in your case I didn't get what I want.

Comment: It sounds fair enough, but what output you get? Can you show it? It's just interesting for me.

Comment: yes i will. JFI, input text will be in one line not a *"\n"* might be that will be issue. You are testing with line by line and i get response from the server in one line.

Comment: @Odedra, yeap, for one line case solution should be different :)

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts and valuable time given in it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import re
a = """<p>Dear Customer,</p><p>This notice serves as proof of delivery for the shipment listed below.</p><dl class="outHozFixed clearfix"><label>Weight:</label></dt><dd>18.00 lbs</dd><dt><label>Shipped&#047;Billed On:</label></dt><dd>09/11/2015</dd><dt><label>Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>12/4/2015 11:07 A.M.</dd><dt><label for="">Signed By:</label></dt><dd>Odedra</dd></dt><dt><label>Left At:</label></dt><dd>Office</dd></dl><p>Thank you for giving us this opportunity to serve you.</p>"""
data = re.search('Delivered On:</label></dt><dd>(.*)$',a)
if data and data.group(1)[:1].isdigit(): 
    data.group(1)[:20]
```

Comment: I added but it's give me output this => '</dd><dt><label for='

Comment: @Odedra, I have added one more check in the answer part. Can you please try with this